# how to convert a string to an int

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file that is reading in Names and Ages printed on the same lines in that order

Example from .txt file:

```
Matt 25

Bob 19

Steve 30
```

How can I split the names and the ages so that I can sort the array by ages?

I have heard to use `line.split("+")` but I am new to java and am unsure of how to implement this.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: Splitting them off is only the first step as you mention needing to *sort* afterward; you still need an association between the age and name. There's number of approaches to that, which I suspect is the point of the homework.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string with the following line (I'm supposing the line you've read is in the variable `line`);

```
String[] bits = line.split("\\s+");
```

then get the integer value with the following:

```
int newInt = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
```

Comment: hey what does ("\\s+") do? why not just (" ")

Comment: @j.con "one or more whitespace characters". It's the safer way to split a sentence on space as it doesn't care the number of spaces between words.

Comment: `"\\s"` means one whitespace character (includes space, tab, and others). `+` means "at least one". Putting them together as `"\\s+"` means "at least one whitespace character".